# $_SESSION is not global when using `SessionCookie` in slim framework?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, slim

I found that if I use `SessionCookie` in slim, `$_SESSION` cannot be retrieved globally.

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie());

function checkAdmin() {
    if ( ! isset($_SESSION['admin']) || $_SESSION['admin'] !== TRUE) {
        exit(NULL);
    }
}

$app->get('/.*', function() use($app) {
    // function checkAdmin() can retrieve the session value I set here
    $_SESSION['admin'] = TRUE;
    $app->render('index.php');
});

$app->post('/loginAdmin', function() use($app) {
    // function checkAdmin() can NOT retrieve the session value I set here
    $_SESSION['admin'] = TRUE;
    exit(TRUE);
});

$app->post('/getAllUsers', 'checkAdmin', function() use($app) {
    // Not related.
});
```

`checkAdmin()` will always `exit(NULL)` if I set `$_SESSION` in the function assigned to `POST /loginAdmin`, so it seems that the session assignment didn't work.

But if I set `$_SESSION` in the function assigned to `GET /`, `checkAdmin` can retrieve it everywhere.

It must be something related to `SessionCookie` because the native session store works fine.

So how can I make it work?

Comment: Because of many frameworks use in-house session implements. You should be use framework session class.

Comment: @AdilIlhan Slim doesn't provide session class, but when adding `SessionCookie` it actually replaces the native session behaviours.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: @LOLKAT Yes. I later found out if you used `SessionCookie`, every session you set will have no effect. Instead, you should use `getCookie()` and `setCookie()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you use the session cookie middleware, you DO NOT need to start a native PHP session. The $_SESSION superglobal will still be available, and it will be persisted into an HTTP cookie via the middleware layer rather than with PHP’s native session management.

so don't use `session cookie middleware`

Comment: What does it mean? I thought if I added `SessionCookie`, the operations I performed on `$_SESSION` would be transformed into cookie operations.

Comment: Now I'm trying to use `getCookie()` and `setCookie()`, and I found out if I use `exit()` after `setCookie()`, the cookie will not be set. What the ...